# How to define fields in a built_value EnumClass?

Tags: dart, code-generation, built-value

I wanted to have a `EnumClass` with an optional `message` field, something like this:

```
class Status extends EnumClass {
  static const Status error = _$error;
  static const Status completed = _$completed;

  String message;

  const Status._(String name) : super(name);

  static BuiltSet<Status> get values => _$values;
  static Status valueOf(String name) => _$valueOf(name);
}
```

The problem is I get this error message:

> Can't define a const constructor for a class with non-final fields.

And if I declare `message` as `final`, then I can't initialize it, since the constructor is hidden.

Is there a way to achieve this? Maybe make a generated Enum Builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of an "enum type" is to create a predefined set of values. If you were to allow clients to create new instances of Status, even const ones, that property would no longer hold; the `valueOf()` method would throw an exception if passed such an instance, and `values` would not contain it. So this violates the contract of an "enum type".

```dart
  // BAD: no longer an "enum type" if clients can create new instances
  const Status.withMessage(String name, String message)
    : message = message, super(name);
```

On the other hand, if the message is constant per enum value and not intended to be provided by clients, you can simply add a getter to the class:

```dart
  // GOOD: Adding new methods, getters, or const-initialized member variables is fine.
  String get message =>
      _messages[this] ??
          (throw StateError('No message for Status.$name'));

  static const _messages = const {
    error: "An error occurred.",
    completed: "Successfully completed."
  };
```

Comment: Well, so built_value EnumClass is not as a Java enum, as many say it is.

Comment: Java also doesn't allow you to create new instances; only to associate constant information with existing instances at the time of definition. It's true there doesn't seem to be a precise equivalent in built_value; the closest equivalent would be to define a getter which indexes into a private map, as in my second example.

Comment: If I remember correctly, in Java we can pass variables at the time of creation of an enum and get their values back, but it has been a while I did it and I am kinda lazy right now to search about on the docs hahaha anyway, what I did in the end was to create a regular Dart `enum` and pass it to `bulit_value` Value Type class that holds an `enum` and an optional `message`.